# Factory pattern:Passing arguments to concrete class

Tags: factory

I have two classes coded to a single interface IStore with one method StoreData(data) - one class sends data to a web service that writes to a DB, the other writes data directly to the DB. (factory pattern)

```
public IStore GetStorageClass(StorageType type)
{
    if (type == StorageType.WebService)
        return new WebService();
    else 
        return new DatabaseStore();
}
```

Now, the DatabaseStore class needs a connection string to work. 
The question is, whose responsibility is it to provide the connection string to the DatabaseStore and how? I thought of:

1. The factory just knows the connection string to pass to DatabaseStore
2. The DatabaseStore constructor reads it from config which the end user has provided.
3. The caller of GetStorageClass, though not aware of the exact implementation, passes a Dictionary of parameters and values where the parameter is connection string (caller knows working with databases needs connection strings)

Which option should I choose and am I using the Factory pattern correctly here? 
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility is to the class containing GetStorageClass. Either it was constructed with a connection string value provided to it's constructor or it has a private method which reads the value from another source.

Passing in a key-value store in addition to the StorageType is going to be too ambigious, the consumer of the API only wants to get an instance of IStore, not configure it as well.

If you need to do configuration for particular IStore implementations you may want to implement the Builder pattern for that implementation and inject the builder into the factory.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. So, in this case, the FactoryProvider class (containing GetCtorageClass) will be the 'director' and instantiate a database specific builder to create DatabaseStore? Still, the configuration (connection string) for the builder ultimately needs to be given by the FactoryProvider, right?

Comment: Consider it this way: Here's a constructor for FactoryProvider  FactoryProvider(DatabaseStoreBuilder dsb) { this.dataStoreBuilder = dsb; } Now, in GetStorageClass your case for DatabaseStore is this.dataStoreBuilder.InitializeDataStore(); The DatabaseStoreBuilder class you passed in was constructed with the connection string to use. The FactoryProvider need not construct the builder itself.